# Диалоговое окно плагина jq UI

Tags: jquery

Как заставить диалоговое окно закрыться при щелчке по любому месту за пределами окна?

```js
$('.dial').dialog({
    autoOpen:false; //Изначально закрыто
});

$('img').click(function(){
  $('.dial').dialog("open"); //По щелчку по картинки открывается  
});

$(document).click(function(){
  $('.dial').dialog('close'); //По щелчку на любом месте закрывается
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <div title="Окно" class="dial">
132
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

3 проблемы:

- внутри объекта не должно быть `;`
- после открытия диалога событие всплывает до документа - имеет смысл это отменить
- имеет смысл не закрывать диалог при клике внутри него

```js
$('.dial').dialog({
    autoOpen: false
});

$('img').click(function (event){
  $('.dial').dialog("open");
  event.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function (event) {
  if (!$(event.target).closest(".dial").length) {
    $('.dial').dialog('close');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/huPUd.jpg?s=128&g=1" />
<div title="Окно" class="dial">132</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.dial').dialog({
    autoOpen:false; //Изначально закрыто.
});

$('img').click(function(){
  $('.dial').dialog("open"); //По щелчку по картинки открывается  
});

  $(document).click(function(event){
  if($(event.target).closest("img, .dial").length) return;
  $('.dial').dialog('close');
});
```

Comment: Золотое правило, прежде чем писать на stackoverflow, лучше загуглить. Может вы свой ответ отметите ответом?)

Comment: Ничего, что в этом коде синтаксическая ошибка?

Comment: Это вы про ; в объекте?

Comment: @DimenSi, да про `;`.